# Make gitlab pipelines with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gitlab, pipeline

I'm exploring gitlab CI/CD and actually I host some websites running wordpress (and joomla). I'm stuck on the planning part of making the pipeline with wordpress. In a fresh wordpress installation, it seems to be easy. The problem is when the site is already running in production, because the developers need to install plugins sometimes and make many changes. I've saw in google that it's possible to install plugins via command line BUT  how the developers will install plugins, and make changes on their local environment and then commit/push to the gitlab? These changes and plugins installation change the database too. If the pipeline has the database restore command from a dump of one of the developers, it will overwrite the database on production. I'm confused about this process. I'm not sure if it's possible to work with pipelines and wordpress.

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.